# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y',

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I want to try out all regressors within the library.
Since I do know, that some of the regressors require more input I build the try and expept catch block.

```py
for name, estimator in sklearn.utils.all_estimators(type_filter='regressor'):
    model =  make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), estimator)
    try:
        scores =  cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring='r2')
        print(name, ': ', np.mean(scores['test_score']))
    except:
        print('Does not get printed.')
```

This returns the following snipped many times:

```
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venvpath\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 598, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "venvpath\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 346, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

In my opinion there are two problems here.
First, exept never gets called.
Second, the y input is not recognized.

I am gratefull for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all_estimators` does not return instances of estimators but only their classes (see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.all_estimators.html)). When defining the pipeline, you should instantiate an object of that class:

```py
for name, estimator in sklearn.utils.all_estimators(type_filter='regressor'):
    model =  make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), estimator()) # <-- change in this line
```

Note the `()` after `estimator`. Now you have actual objects that can be fitted to data.

---

Concerning the `except` block: by default, `cross_validate` will just assign `np.nan` to the score if an error occurs. To actually raise the error, set `error_score='raise'` in `cross_validate`:

```py
scores =  cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring='r2', error_score='raise')
```

Comment: the code runs now. The except block still doesnt work for the estimators that require more input

Comment: @TomS you need to set `error_score='raise'` in `cross_validate`. Edited the answer.